# Querystring not found in Custom API get method

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to read some parameters in the GET method from my custom API, although Azure Mobile Services is always returning this error:

Error in script '/api/customapi.js'. TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
    at C:\DWASFiles\Sites\XXXXXXXXX-android\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\api\customapi.js:17:49
    [external code]

The requested URL is like this: https://XXXXXXXXXX-android.azure-mobile.net/api/customapi?lat=-19&lng=-43

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    // Use "request.service" to access features of your mobile service, e.g.:
    //   var tables = request.service.tables;
    //   var push = request.service.push;

    response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Hello World!' });
};

exports.get = function(request, response) {
    if (request.parameters !== null) {

        var req = require("request");
        console.log("lat: " + request.parameters.lat);
        console.log("lng: " + request.parameters.lng);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In custom APIs, the `request` parameter passed has the same properties as the [request object](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) used in `express.js`. To access the query string, you'd use `request.query`:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var httpReq = require("request");
    var lat = request.query.lat; // the type of the variable is a string; use something like parseFloat if you want it as a number
    var lng = request.query.lng;
    response.send(200, { lat: lat, lng: lng });
};
```